# jQuery slice() and remove() then call jQuery isotope to rearrange layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I am working on this site http://www.mtgmusic.no/

What i want there is to only show 25 posts and rearrange the whole post divs(`.dcsns-li`) by calling isotope again.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  var nPosts = jQuery(".dcsns-li").length;
  console.log(nPosts);
  var deletePost = nPosts - 25;
  jQuery('body').find(".dcsns-li").slice(-nPosts,-deletePost).remove();

  var $container = $('.stream');
  $container.isotope({
     // options
    itemSelector: '.dcsns-li',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });
});
```

The problem with this code is i am getting an inconsistent alignment of those divs. Sometimes the divs are gathering on the left side, they are lining on the left(this occasionally happens, weird eh?)

I am also getting big gaps on those divs [image]

Is there any way to fix this one or any work around?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Comment: can you move the `$container.isotope(...)` to a `setTimeout()` like `setTimeout(function(){$container.isotope()}, 10)`

Comment: also try `jQuery('body').find(".dcsns-li").slice(-25).remove()` instead of `jQuery('body').find(".dcsns-li").slice(-nPosts,-deletePost).remove()`

Comment: Hi @ArunPJohny, it's you again :) Thanks for your answer.I think this code `jQuery('body').find(".dcsns-li").slice(-25).remove()` would not retain 25 posts, but delete 25 posts. I was hoping to only display 25 posts, not delete 25 posts. Anyway, i'll try that setTimeout. :)

Comment: you are right... misunderstood the requirement - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wtdu53j0/1/

Answer (score 0):

to avoid gaps use masonry layout

```
$container.isotope({ layoutMode: 'masonry' });
```

see [layout mode documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer man. By the way, this is what I was referring on the divs that are lining on the left http://screencast.com/t/mZQLwELQofV9

Comment: if div's are still on the left check if there are any errors while your code runs. might be that the code exits before the layout is applied.